# EXPO android network error with https on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

On ios requests work correctly, but on android with https for some reason trouble. I have an assumption that ssl is connected on the server to the ip address, ie looks like this https://{ip_address}/ .
Tried throwing a request through android to google and other platforms, works properly. But why then on ios device everything works fine? Has anyone encountered something like this?

I tried fetch

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.